# Using perl __DATA__ assign its value to variable

Tags: perl, safefilehandle

I am trying to use the filehandle **DATA** in a script, assign the values to a variable, and when it prints it just prints and empty string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);  
my $str = <DATA> ;
print "$str\n" ;

__DATA__
ab cd ef gh ij
```

Comment: That code prints `ab cd ef gh ij` (followed by two line feeds), not "an empty string".

Comment: yes it does - I have no idea what happened before.

Comment: It's possible that you had an extra blank line after `__DATA__` before the line `ab cd ef gh ij` in your original code that was producing the problem you're describing. Since you are reading from `<DATA>` in scalar context without manipulating `$/`, you are only getting the first line of data. If that first line happened to be empty, you would see no visible output other than some blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one line in `__DATA__`, you might want to use "slurp" (read the entire content of `<DATA>` into a variable):

```perl
my $str = do { local $/ = undef; <DATA> };
print "$str\n";
__DATA__
ab cd
ef gh
i
j
```

Comment: or just `my $str = join '', <DATA>`

Comment: The data set I was using had more than one line. thank you